# Logout of my app if logged out of facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app that uses facebook connect. When it has to login to facebook it opens up the android app on the phone. But after that the app works independently of facebook. What I want to do is that if the user logs out of facebook on the facebook app my app should also sign out autmomatically. How can this be done?

Comment: Does the facebook app send any `broadcast` about logout or login? You could then receive the broadcast and act upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get notified if a user is logged out of the facebook app. The only thing you can do is to clear the facebook OAuth token everytime your application is closed.

This way the user would have to go through the facebook login process every time she opens the app. If the facebook app is logged in this will be very fast. If the user is logged out she will have to log in in facebook again to use your app.